# Updating / inserting once and then exit

Tags: php, sql

Hope some of you pros can help me out on this sql / php issue.

The short version:

I need to add members to a task-database. So I have memberlist, it loop through each member and runs below sql.

I need to run an SQL statement that is to exit after first update / execution where it hits the parameters. So I need some kind of return for each time the sql updates a field?

Pseudocode:

```
Update this column
condition 1
condition 2
after first execution exit
```

Current sql:

```
UPDATE calendar
SET spil1 = '$temp'
WHERE spil1 IS NOT NULL
AND
(dayname = 'Lørdag'
OR dayname = 'Søndag')
```

// now exit if the above is met and the sql update was executed.

So the problem is I cannot make it stop (tried limit, top etc)
How is this made with SQL? or is there a smart way to condition it in the PHP loop before executing the script?

Comment: @anduan200 . . . Ta your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would really help too.  Your question mentions things like "memberlist" and parameters, and I don't see what they have to do with the existing query.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an id column in calendar? If yes use the following query (Not tested):

```
UPDATE calendar
SET spil1 = '$temp'
WHERE id =
(SELECT id FROM
(SELECT * FROM calendar
WHERE spil1 IS NOT NULL
AND
(dayname = 'Lørdag'
OR dayname = 'Søndag')
LIMIT 1)T)
```

What this query does, it brings the first record that applies to your condition, and then update that record the way you want it

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this does not solve it. I have an id, but the issue is I need a way to stop the update from executing when it has inserted something once.

Comment: try this query, forgot to add an alias. It should work, I tested it.
UPDATE calendar
 SET spil1 = '$temp'
 WHERE id =
 (SELECT id FROM
 (SELECT * FROM calendar
 WHERE spil1 IS NOT NULL
 AND
 (dayname = 'Lørdag'
 OR dayname = 'Søndag')
 LIMIT 1)T)

Comment: What this query does, it brings the first record that applies to your condition, and then update that record the way you want it

Comment: You sir, are a genious... Very well written code!! thank you so much!

Comment: I would like to vore your comment up, but i cannot as i have less than 15 reputation

Comment: You are very welcome, you can vote my post as correct as it is edited

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any unique id put this code at the end of your query..
good luck.

```
AND unique_id IN ( SELECT unique_id FROM calendar order by unique_id ASC LIMIT 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want to assign a different member to each `NULL` value in the calendar table.  This is tricky.  It requires enumerating the rows in each table for the `join` -- and assumes a unique id in the calendar table.

```
update calendar c join
       (select c.*,
               row_number() over (order by c2.pil1) as seqnum
        from calendar c2
        where c2.pil1 is not null and
              c2.dayname in ('Lørdag', 'Søndag')
       ) c2
       on c.calendar_id = c2.calendar_id join  -- the unique id
       (select ml.*,
               row_number() over (order by ml.member_id) as seqnum
        from memberlist ml
       ) ml
       on ml.seqnum = c2.seqnum
    set c.spil1 = ml.member_id;
```

I also suspect that you want the condition for the `calendar` table to be `IS NULL` rather than `IS NOT NULL`, but this is the logic you have in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I used the code from mustafaj and it worked perfectly. Your suggestion might work too but mustafaj's suggestion worked perfectly so im sticking with that. However, you are perfectly right about that I wanted to look up IS NULL instead of IS NOT NULL - my bad there.

Comment: @anduen200 . . . This code does not require you to loop through the tables.  It does the entire update at once, which should be a big win.